# View Code When Modal Dialog Is Open In Excel

Tags: vba, excel

This may be a stupid question, but I feel like I'm in a pickle.  I have a modal UserForm that opens when an Excel workbook is opened.  When the UserForm is closed, the Excel workbook is saved and closed.  I need to be able to view my code, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that because if I close the modal dialog box, the workbook closes.  Does anyone know how I can view my code?  I really apologize if this is a stupid question, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for you time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without restarting the workbook i.e when the userform is shown in modal, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> to get into the VBE

Depending on laptops the key combination might change. Here is another which you can try.

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Hold the shift key when opening the workbook. This allows you to open office applications with macros not running and can be useful in situations like this.

Then view the macros (hit Alt+F11 to open it this editor).

Answer (score 0):

The two other suggestions are good. For easiest debugging, I'd put the code that opens the userform in a separate routine and then call that routine from Workbook_Open. That way you can run and debug your code without having to re-open the workbook.

Then your ThisWorkbook module might look something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
MyUserformProcedure
End Sub

Sub MyUserformProcedure()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

You could then comment out the line in `Workbook_Open` and call `MyUserformProcedure`, and uncomment the line when you're finished debugging.